# Is this a good practice to make a one to one relation table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

mysql dbms used

i have created a customer table

```
create table customer
(id int ,
name varchar(3),
primary key(id));
```

now i make another table address where i am making the unique foreign key (id )from customer table

```
create table customer_add
(hno int ,
block_name varchar(3),
street_no int,
town varchar(20),
state varchar(20),
cust_id int unique,
primary key(hno),
foreign key(cust_id) references winecustomer(id));
```

is this a wrong method ?if yes how should i make one to one relation?
is there any  relation other than onetoone ,onetomany,manytomany?

Comment: unless you have some overwhelming reason against (e.g. massive table that cannot tolerate downtime while you `alter` it, or you ran into mysql's max-cols-per-table limit), there's very little point in having a straight 1:1 table.

Comment: @MarcB yeah even i think so there is no practical scenario(normally) where there is need of 1:1 , but imagine the customer address table is needed separately for xyz reason then is this approach correct?

Comment: yep. as long as you remember that the FK only goes one way. it won't help if you delete a custom_add record, leaving the record in customer without its "twin".

Answer (score 0):

Based off an ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram), there can be 1 to 1 Relationships. However when you create your table you choose which one gets the primary key of the other table and therefore becomes a foreign key. In an ERD you can also determine which one should have the other tables primary key by seeing which one has TOTAL/FULL participation.

Example:
Employee ---1----- (has) ----1--- (Manager)

Here we say one employee has one manager, and manager has one employee. Lets say employee has Employee_SSN attribute then inside Manager Table we can take the Employee_SSN as a foreign key that refers to the Employee Table. Or, lets say Manager has M_SSN, then Employee takes M_SSN as a foreign key that refers to the Manager Table. However if one of them had FULL/Total participation, then that one would receive the primary key of the other table. It is totally okay to have 1 to 1 relationships, (A 1 to 1, relationship is easier and clearer to see in an ERD).